# Does writeObject(Object obj) write the whole class of the object?

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

Regarding the method `writeObject(Object obj)` from `ObjectOutputStream` class

From Javadocs:

> Write the specified object to the ObjectOutputStream. The class of the
>   object, the signature of the class, and the values of the
>   non-transient and non-static fields of the class and all of its
>   supertypes are written.

What does the Statement

> The class of the object

mean? Does that mean that the .class File is writen to the file or the source code of the class or only the name of the class?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the class, so that when the `ObjectInputStream` reads it back in it knows what class to instantiate. It doesn't need the source code of the class, just its name.

Comment: I have also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it if someone is interested